# Python modifying original variable instead of creating new one

Tags: python, pointers

I am having an issue with BFS for solving the 8 puzzle in python. I need the move method to return a new puzzle instead of modifying the original. The output below shows the original puzzle is being modified instead of a new puzzle being produced. I tried copy but that didn't work and lists don't have a deep copy. Is there a simple way to make a new object from an original?

```
def move(puzzle, direction):
    # find where the zero (gap) is and swap in the given direction    
    row_count = 0
    for row in puzzle:
        if '0' in row:
            gapx = row.index('0')
            gapy = row_count
        row_count = row_count + 1

    # move it accordingly, as long as the move is legal
    if direction == 'up' and (gapy==1 or gapy==2):
        temp = puzzle[gapy-1][gapx]
        puzzle[gapy-1][gapx] = '0'
        puzzle[gapy][gapx] = temp
        return puzzle


pretty_print(puzzle_state)
new_puzzle = move(puzzle_state, 'up')
pretty_print(puzzle_state)
```

Output:

```
123
804
765

103
824
765
```

Comment: why do you think you cannot `deepcopy` a list?

Comment: Looks like I was using it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy.deepcopy() worked, I was originally trying puzzle.deepcopy() which is not the proper way to use deep copy. Thanks!